# How to solve $(1+xy) y\,dx + (1-xy)x\,dy = 0$ by sepatation, as a linear equation or homogeneous?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this ODE?

> $$(1+xy) y\,dx + (1-xy)x\,dy = 0$$

We have been taught only these 3 types of problems: separable, linear equations or homogeneous. I tried using these methods, but I don't think this is a homogeneous or a linear differential equation. I tried separating the variables but couldn't. I strongly believe that this can be only solved by separating variables otherwise the question is wrong.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT :

A part $y(x)=0$ and $x(y)=0$ which both are trivial solutions :
$$y'(x)= -\frac{(1+xy)y}{(1-xy)x}$$
$t(x)=xy \quad \implies \quad t'=y+xy'=\frac{t}{x}-\frac{(1+t)t}{(1-t)x} = -\frac{2t}{(1-t)x}$

$$dt = -\frac{2t}{(1-t)x}dx$$

This is a separable ODE : I suppose that you know how to continue.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why i was not able to do it, I tried that too, something must have went wrong

Comment: Which will again lead the marvelous Lambert function !

Comment: Without the miraculous Lambert function, one have to be satisfied with an implicit form of solution !